# How to convert JDBC connection from Tomcat implementation to Jetty?

Tags: java, rest, tomcat, jetty

In my project, earlier we were using Tomcat as a container for hosting JAX-RS REST-API. 
It is connection to Oracle using JDBC.
For that I had used META-INF/context.xml to specify my connection details:

```
<Resource name="jdbc/myconnmapping" factory="my.package.EncryptedDataSourceFactory"
            auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource" driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"
            url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@//my.oracle.server:1555/jobctlss1"
            username="TOM" password="NQp5gwJdXs5KIts4OqiFN1qI/HhhRs9/eeO2lwVVL7dA+" maxActive="100" maxIdle="50"
            maxWait="-1" />
```

I had also used encryption for password in the `<Resource>` tag in which I had defined the `factory="my.package.EncryptedDataSourceFactory"` parameter.

Then im my connection class I was using his code to connect to oracle:

```
Context initContext = new InitialContext();
Context envContext = (Context)initContext.lookup("java:/comp/env");
ds = (DataSource)envContext.lookup("jdbc/myconnmapping");

Connection con = ds.getConnection();
Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver");

Statement stmt = this.con.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE,ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
```

And till now it was working all good until we changed the server to Jetty, and the JDBC is giving connection error, when I am delpoying the same WAR file in Jetty's webapp.

It'll be of great help if anyone can provide a same `<resource-ref>` entry in web.xml, where I can call my custom `DataSourceFactory` class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely you have to add a jetty-env.xml file containing the database connection metadata.